# Forma eficiente de vaciar tablas en ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, optimización

Tengo un procedimiento que vacía una tabla auxiliar y lo vuelve a cargar cada vez que es invocado. El comando utilizado para eliminar todos los registros es:

```
DELETE FROM T1;
```

Para mi sorpresa eliminar `500.000` registros con este comando tuvo un coste de aproximadamente `8 segundos`.

Después de varias pruebas añadí la clausula `WHERE` de la siguiente manera:

```
DELETE FROM T1 WHERE 1=1;
```

Este último redujo el tiempo considerablemente a unos `3 segundos` aproximadamente.

¿Exista alguna otra forma más eficiente de eliminar todos los registros de una tabla?

Comment: Puedes probar con TRUNCATE TABLE T1  el comando TRUNCATE elimina los registros de la tabla y reinicia los autoincrementales, pero no borra la tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para borrar todos los registros de una tabla tienes algunas opciones, cada una tiene sus diferencias, en cuanto a performance, creo que éste sería el orden de mejor a peor.

#### `TRUNCATE`

- Es un comando [DDL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm#i2099120)
- Borra todos los registros
- No se ejecutan triggers
- No es posible hacer un `ROLLBACK`
- No afecta las dependencias de la tabla: índices, permisos o triggers

#### `DROP TABLE`

- Es un comando [DDL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm#i2099120)
- Borra todos los registros junto con las dependencias de la tabla: permisos, triggers, índices, etc.
- No se ejecutan triggers
- No es posible hacer un `ROLLBACK`
- Nos obliga a recrear la tabla junto a sus dependencias.

#### `DELETE` sin `WHERE`

- Es un comando [DML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm#i2099257)
- Borra todos los registros
- Es posible realizar un `ROLLBACK` de la operación
- Eventualmente se ejecuta el trigger asociado

Mayor detalle de las diferencias vas a poder encontrar en [este](http://www.oratable.com/delete-truncate-drop/) artículo.

PD: Me llama mucho la atención tu comentario acerca del `WHERE 1=1`, no encuentro razón para que el optimizador de la consulta haga una diferencia solo con ese filtro. Por otro lado el tiempo que demora una consulta no es un buen indicador la mayoría de las veces, dependiendo de la carga de trabajo del servidor una misma operación puede variar mucho, es preferible ver cosas como cantidad de lecturas/escrituras.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no sabía de la existencia del `TRUNCATE` y como mencionas que es un comando `DDL` me imagino que tengo que ejecutar el `GRANT` para dar privilegios de ejecución a usuarios, pero eso ya es otra historia. Es el más eficiente para el caso que estoy necesitando.

Comment: Referente al rendimiento del `WHERE` sin filtro y el `WHERE 1=1` tampoco encuentro razón del porque hay diferencias en el rendimiento utilizando el último. Saludos cordiales!

Answer (score -1):

TRUNCATE es mucho mas rápido que DELETE. Solo que con TRUNCATE vas a borrar **todo** lo que hay en la tabla sin ninguna distinción.

Si en algún momento necesitas controlar que eliminar vas a tener que usar DELETE.